# Is there a way to delete or replace the next line in a csv file when using a loop?

Tags: c#, csv, delete-row, readlines

I am wondering if I can delete or replace a line in the csv file each time the file has the word "hello". So when I print the file back to the console it shows everything but the lines that say "hello". What I have done so far is below, I loop over each line in the file checking if the line equals "hello" but don't know what to do next.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Var allLines = File.ReadLines(@"..\..\..\File.csv");

Foreach (var line in allLines)

{

if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(string Hello))

{

// need to delete line where the line in csv file equals hello

}

}
```

Comment: If you want to just not print the line where that condition is matched, negate the condition and move your Console WriteLine inside it.

Comment: You could write the data to a new csv file, omitting lines that you do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq to only go over the lines that you are interested in

```
Foreach (var line in allLines.Where(x => !x.Split(',').First().Equals("hello")  ))
{
  // do what u need with anything not hello
}
```

This loops through all lines that does "not" equal "hello". You can replace Equals with Contains if you want to remove line that might contain hello

If your intention is to remove it from the file, you can use the same kind of linq statement,

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, allLines.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("hello,"))  );
```